# Why do I need to import enum classes to use them when I already imported the package they're in? [Java]

Tags: java, class, import, enums, package

I'm having a little confusion regarding importing packages in Java.

So I have a class with nested enum classes inside:

```
public class AirCraft extends PublicTransportation 
{
    private AirType classType;
    private TimeType maintainType;
    
    //default constructor
    public AirCraft() {
        super();
        classType = AirType.NONE;
        maintainType = TimeType.NONE;
    }
    
    //nested enums used for AirCraft attributes (2)
    public enum AirType {
        NONE,
        HELICOPTER,
        AIRLINE,
        BALLOON,
        GLIDER
    }
    
    public enum TimeType{
        NONE,
        WEEKLY,
        MONTHLY,
        YEARLY
    }
```

Then in my driver class I have:

```
import airTransport.*; //importing the AirCraft class in which resides the two enum classes

public class DriverTransport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //testing AirCraft class methods
        AirCraft secondAir = new AirCraft(50.9, 10, AirType.HELICOPTER, TimeType.MONTHLY);
    }
}
```

However, I receive a "cannot be resolved to a variable" error for AirType and TimeType. It is fixed if I import them separately, but I'd like to understand why simply importing AirCraft class does not work even though these two enums are inside AirCraft class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have used inner enumeration so you have to refer to it via the class it is in:

```
AirCraft secondAir = new AirCraft(50.9, 10, AirCraft.AirType.HELICOPTER, AirCraft.TimeType.MONTHLY);
```

you can also statically import the entire enum and use it the way you originally wanted:

```
import static other.AirCraft.*;
```

and then:

```
AirCraft secondAir = new AirCraft(50.9, 10, AirType.HELICOPTER, AirCraft.TimeType.MONTHLY);
```

Comment: Would it be better to have the enums separated into distinct class files, and then simply importing the whole package containing both enums in my driver file, or is it better to use directly like ```AirCraft.AirType.HELICOPTER```?

Comment: @HelloWorld  You can do it any way that makes sense to you. If your enum is meant to be used in other code on its own, put the enum in its own class. If the enum really only makes sense when used within the context of a particular class, then nest the enum. For example, colors. An enum listing all the standard [colors named in CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#CSS_colors) should be in its own class, as many kinds of code may use that. An enum listing colors used in color-coding parts of your aircraft should be nested within the `AirCraft` class, its only sensible context.